# Convert UTC time_t to UTC tm

Tags: c++, time, data-conversion

All my internal times are UTC stored in `time_t`. I need to convert them to `struct tm`. If I use [`localtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) the time is correct, except that `tm_isdst` may be set resulting in the time being off an hour. If I use [`gmtime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime) it gets the wrong time, off by the time zone difference.

**Edit** I am looking for a cross platform solution that works in Windows and Linux

Comment: Are you setting env var `TZ` as stated in `localtime` reference page? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime

Comment: Sorry, just made an edit. I am looking for something cross platform, and I don't believe Windows has that environment variable

Comment: "If I use gmtime it gets the wrong time, off by the time zone difference." --> Perhaps your expectation are incorrect as `gmtime()` should be the correct approach.  Post code used, sample `time_t` input, complete `struct tm` output, expected output for good answers.

Comment: What does it mean: `except that tm_isdst may be set resulting in the time being off an hour`? Can you provide an example, [mcve] if possible.

Comment: What does this print on your system? `time_t ttt = 0; puts(asctime(gmtime(&ttt)));`

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. "Thu Jan  1 00:00:00 1970\n"

Comment: @MarekR What is means, it since I have a time_t is UTC already, I can't use `gmtime()`, because it expects a time_t in local time that is adjusts, so I must use `localctime()` which sets the time based on DST settings. If not for DST, the time would be correct. These doesn't seem to be a function to turn a time_t into a struct tm when said time_t is already UTC

Comment: The value 0 signifies zero seconds since Jan 1 00:00:00 1970 UTC. So `gmtime` converts UTC time to UTC time, as it should. It does not, and should not, adjust anything.  If you have `time_t` in UTC, `gmtime` should convert it to `struct tm` in UTC, exactly as you are asking. If you think this is not the case, please show a specific value of `time_t` and a specific `struct tm` it gets converted.

Comment: I do believe my problem is elsewhere. It appears that `mktime` is the culprit. I have a struct tm that is manually populated with the UTC time, but after I call `mktime` the hour is changed by one to accomodate DST. Hence, all times from that point on are wrong by one hour. I hadn't noticed the struct tm was changed because it was just temporary. I read some bad documentation on IBM's website that states `mktime` works on UTC time, but the GNU documentation states that it works on local time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a cross platform solution that requires C++11 or better, and a [free, open-source, header-only date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  And when your vendor brings you C++20, you can loose the [date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) as it is incorporated into C++20 `<chrono>`.

It is actually easier to convert from `time_t` to a UTC `tm` by going through `<chrono>` than it is to use the C API.  There do exist various extensions to do this on each platform, but the extensions have different syntaxes.  This solution has a uniform syntax across all platforms.

In C++11, though not specified, it is a de-facto standard that both `time_t` and `std::chrono::system_clock` track [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), though at different precisions.  In C++20 this becomes specified for `std::chrono::system_clock`.  For `time_t` the de-facto precision is `seconds`.  One can take advantage of this knowledge to create extremely efficient conversions between the C API and the C++ `<chrono>` API.

### Step 1:  Convert `time_t` to a `chrono::time_point`

This is very easy and efficient:

```
date::sys_seconds
to_chrono(std::time_t t)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    return sys_seconds{seconds{t}};
}
```

`date::sys_seconds` is simply a type alias for:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds>
```

I.e. a `time_point` based on `system_clock` but with `seconds` precision.

All this function does is change type from `time_t` to `seconds` and then to `time_point`.  No actual computation is done.  Here is an optimized clang compilation of `to_chrono`:

```
    .globl  __Z9to_chronol          ## -- Begin function _Z9to_chronol
    .p2align    4, 0x90
__Z9to_chronol:                         ## @_Z9to_chronol
    .cfi_startproc
## %bb.0:
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc
```

All that's there is the boiler plate for a function call.  And if you inline this, even that disappears.

Furthermore this function will port to C++20 by simply removing `using namespace date` and changing `date::sys_seconds` to `std::chrono::sys_seconds`.

### Step 2:  Convert `sys_seconds` to a `tm`

This is where the computation happens:

```
std::tm
to_tm(date::sys_seconds tp)
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    auto td = floor<days>(tp);
    year_month_day ymd = td;
    hh_mm_ss<seconds> tod{tp - td};  // <seconds> can be omitted in C++17
    tm t{};
    t.tm_sec  = tod.seconds().count();
    t.tm_min  = tod.minutes().count();
    t.tm_hour = tod.hours().count();
    t.tm_mday = unsigned{ymd.day()};
    t.tm_mon  = (ymd.month() - January).count();
    t.tm_year = (ymd.year() - 1900_y).count();
    t.tm_wday = weekday{td}.c_encoding();
    t.tm_yday = (td - sys_days{ymd.year()/January/1}).count();
    t.tm_isdst = 0;
    return t;
}
```

All of the computation happens in the first three lines:

```
auto td = floor<days>(tp);
year_month_day ymd = td;
hh_mm_ss<seconds> tod{tp - td};  // <seconds> can be omitted in C++17
```

Then the rest of the function just extracts the fields to fill out the `tm` members.

```
auto td = floor<days>(tp);
```

The first line above simply truncates the precision of the `time_point` from `seconds` to `days`, rounding down towards negative infinity (even for `time_point`s prior to the 1970-01-01 epoch).  This is little more than a divide by 86400.

```
year_month_day ymd = td;
```

The second line above takes the count of days since the epoch and converts it to a `{year, month, day}` data structure.  This is where most of the computation happens.

```
hh_mm_ss<seconds> tod{tp - td};  // <seconds> can be omitted in C++17
```

The third line above subtracts the days-precision `time_point` from the seconds-precision `time_point` resulting in a `std::chrono::seconds` time duration since midnight UTC.  This duration is then broken out into a `{hours, minutes, seconds}` data structure (the type `hh_mm_ss`).  In C++17 this line can optionally be simplified to:

```
hh_mm_ss tod{tp - td};  // <seconds> can be omitted in C++17
```

Now `to_tm` simply extracts the fields to fill out the `tm` according to the [C API](https://cigix.me/c17#7.27.1).

```
int   tm_sec;        //   seconds after the minute -- [0, 60]
int   tm_min;        //   minutes after the hour -- [0, 59]
int   tm_hour;       //   hours since midnight -- [0, 23]
int   tm_mday;       //   day of the month -- [1, 31]
int   tm_mon;        //   months since January -- [0, 11]
int   tm_year;       //   years since 1900

int tm_wday; // days since Sunday -- [0, 6]
int tm_yday; // days since January 1 -- [0, 365]
int tm_isdst; // Daylight Saving Time flag
```

It is important to first zero-initialize the `tm` because different platforms have extra `tm` data members as extensions that are best given the value 0.

```
tm t{};
```

For the hours, minutes and seconds one simply extracts the appropriate `chrono::duration` from `tod` and then extracts the integral values with the `.count()` member function:

```
t.tm_sec  = tod.seconds().count();
t.tm_min  = tod.minutes().count();
t.tm_hour = tod.hours().count();
```

`day` has an explicit conversion to `unsigned` and this is one of the few places where the C API doesn't give a `tm` data member an unexpected bias:

```
t.tm_mday = unsigned{ymd.day()};
```

`tm_mon` is defined as "months since January" so that bias has to be taken into account.  One can subtract `January` from the `month`, resulting in a `months` *duration*.  This is a `chrono::duration`, and the integral value can be extracted with the `.count()` member function:

```
t.tm_mon  = (ymd.month() - January).count();
```

Similarly, `tm_year` is years since 1900:

```
t.tm_year = (ymd.year() - 1900_y).count();
```

One can convert a days-precision `time_point` (`td`) to a `weekday` with conversion syntax, and then `weekday` has a member function `.c_encoding()` to extract an integral value which matches the C API:  days since Sunday -- [0, 6].  Alternatively there is also a `.iso_encoding()` member function if one desires the ISO encoding [Mon, Sun] -> [1, 7].

```
t.tm_wday = weekday{td}.c_encoding();
```

`tm_yday` is days since January 1 -- [0, 365].  This is easily computed by subtracting the first of the year from the days-precision `time_point` (`td`), creating a `days` `chrono::duration`:

```
t.tm_yday = (td - sys_days{ymd.year()/January/1}).count();
```

Finally `tm_isdst` should be set to 0 to indicate Daylight Saving Time is not in effect.  Technically this step was already done when zero-initializing `tm`, but is repeated here for readability purposes:

```
t.tm_isdst = 0;
```

`to_tm` can be ported to C++20 by:

- remove `using namespace date;`
- change `date::sys_seconds` to `std::chrono::sys_seconds`
- change `1900_y` to `1900y`

### Example Use:

Given a `time_t`, here is how you can use these functions to convert it to a UTC `tm`:

```
std::time_t t = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm tm = to_tm(to_chrono(t));
```

Here are the necessary headers:

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
```

Or in C++20, just:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great information. I have been hesitant to learn the chrono stuff because the cross platform support isn't great yet for C++11 and 14, but at some point we need to force them to upgrade. Appreciate the depth of this answer

Comment: If it helps, here is a video tutorial on C++11/14 `<chrono>`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It will cost you an hour.